# How to prove that if $\sum a_n^2 $ ,$\sum b_n^2$ converges then $\sum a_nb_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> How to prove that if $\sum a_n^2 $ ,$\sum b_n^2$ converges then $\sum a_nb_n$ converges

I wanted to prove above .

I tried summation by parts but I did not get.

> Please Just give me hint. Because I wanted to try this problem

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply Cauchy - Schwarz inequality to $\sum_{n=j}^{k} a_nb_n$.